# LaTeX, dvipng and pipes

Tags: png, dvi

I am trying to create PNG images for each page in a LaTeX document on the fly. Since the startup time of LaTeX is the limiting factor for speed I tried the following approach using names pipes:

Bash 1 (listening):

```
mknod test.dvi p # create named pipe 'test.dvi'
dvipng test.dvi  # let dvipng wait for input on that named pipe
```

Bash 2 (sending):

```
echo "\\documentclass{article}\\pagestyle{empty}\\begin{document}text\\end{document}" \ 
    | latex -jobname=test # typeset small LaTeX document into test.dvi
```

The LaTeX run finishes successfully. But dvipng quits with the following error:

```
dvipng: Fatal error, POST occurs within page
```

Surprisingly, dvipng works as expected when I redirect the `test.dvi` to a regular file using

```
cat test.dvi > test2.dvi
dvipng test2.dvi # results in test21.png
```

on Bash 1.

Hopefully, I can sent continuous data to LaTeX so that dvipng outputs a `.png` each time `latex` outputs a page to `test.dvi`. If you have better approaches than the one above please let me know! Note that I also precompiled the preamble of the LaTeX document. But this is still not fast enough.

Comment: Is it easier to create a pdf and convert that into individual pngs?

Comment: Maybe pdflatex and a tool for png conversion would solve the pipe related issue. But pdflatex is slow compared to latex. Also, dvipng is very fast. Currently I use a RAM disk to solve the speed issue. But using pipes would be much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to investigate the [TeX-daemon](https://bitbucket.org/jfine/tex-daemon): It comes with a special program dvichop than can extract new pages from TeX's dvi-output piped into it.

Comment: But how does this help in creating PNG files for these pages?

Comment: @porst17: My impression was that your problem starts with getting correct dvi pages continuously from LaTeX.

Comment: I clicked on the link but it says "repo not found"